# "event.target as Checkbox" is passing different value of "selected" property through Mouse CLICK event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have a checkbox for which I am setting the "selected" property programmatically. After setting the value, a mouse-click handler comes into action and rest of the logic lies in there.

The event handler is able to fetch the selected Checkbox via:

```
event.target as CheckBox;
```

But it is not fetching the proper value of the "selected" property. For e.g. if I set the property to "FALSE", then after fetching the CheckBox, it's value is found to be "TRUE".
This behavior is very weird, and I never faced such issue before.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated!

Following is the code snapshot:

CheckBox.selected is set to FALSE:

```
filterUIObject.filterCheckBox.selected = false;
filterUIObject.filterCheckBox.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

filterUIObject is an Object which is holding references to multiple controls and containers as shown below:

```
var filterUIObject:Object = new Object();               
            var cbSelected:Boolean = false;
            var tiValue:String = "";
            var dateFilterName:String = dateByVariableFilterNames.getItemAt(i) as String;


            var dateByVarCB:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
            dateByVarCB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkBoxClickHandler);
            dateByVarCB.id = dateFilterName+"_CB"; 
            dateByVarCB.name = dateFilterName;
            dateByVarCB.label = dateFilterName;
            dateByVarCB.toolTip = RB.getString('Common.ToolTip.SelectOccurrences.txt');

            //dateByVarCB.selected = cbSelected;

            // Creates last <TextInput> occurrences
            var lastOccurrencesTI:TextInput = new TextInput();
            lastOccurrencesTI.id = dateFilterName+"_TI";
            lastOccurrencesTI.name = dateFilterName+"_TI";
            lastOccurrencesTI.toolTip = RB.getString('Common.ToolTip.Occurrences.txt');
            lastOccurrencesTI.width = 30
            lastOccurrencesTI.text = ""+tiValue;
            lastOccurrencesTI.restrict = RESTRICT_TO_CHARS;
            lastOccurrencesTI.maxChars = 2;

            var occurrencesLabel:Label = new Label();
            occurrencesLabel.text = RB.getString('GallerySecondaryFilterPage.Occurrences.label.txt');

            var eachRowContainer:GridRow = new GridRow();

            var gridItem:GridItem = new GridItem();

            var filterContainerVB:VBox = new VBox();
            filterContainerVB.id = dateFilterName;
            filterContainerVB.name = dateFilterName;
            filterContainerVB.percentWidth = 33;
            filterContainerVB.height = 65;

            var horizontalContainer:HBox;
            horizontalContainer = new HBox();
            horizontalContainer.percentWidth = 100
            horizontalContainer.percentHeight = 100;

            var spaceVarLabel:Label = new Label();
            spaceVarLabel.text = "";
            horizontalContainer.addChild(spaceVarLabel);
            horizontalContainer.addChild(lastOccurrencesTI);
            horizontalContainer.addChild(occurrencesLabel);

            filterContainerVB.addChild(dateByVarCB);
            filterContainerVB.addChild(horizontalContainer);
            gridItem.addChild(filterContainerVB);

            eachRowContainer.addChild(gridItem);
            this.addChild(eachRowContainer);

            // update data in filterUIObject.
            filterUIObject.filterContainer = eachRowContainer;
            filterUIObject.dateFilterName = dateFilterName;
            filterUIObject.filterCheckBox = dateByVarCB; 
            filterUIObject.filterTextInput = lastOccurrencesTI;                              
            filterUIObject.filterOccurrencesLabel = occurrencesLabel;
            filterUIObjects[i] = filterUIObject;
```

This is the event handler:

```
    private function checkBoxClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var selectedCheckBox:CheckBox = event.target as CheckBox;
        var checkBoxID:String = selectedCheckBox.id;

        if(selectedCheckBox.selected)
        {
            for each(var filterUIObject:Object in filterUIObjects)
            {
                if(checkBoxID == filterUIObject.filterCheckBox.id)
                {
                    filterUIObject.filterOccurrencesLabel.enabled = true;
                    filterUIObject.filterTextInput.enabled = true;
                    //filterUIObject.filterTextInput.text = DEFAULT_OCCURENCE_VALUE;
                    break;                      
                }
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            for each(filterUIObject in filterUIObjects)
            {
                if(checkBoxID == filterUIObject.filterCheckBox.id)
                {
                    filterUIObject.filterOccurrencesLabel.enabled = false;
                    filterUIObject.filterTextInput.enabled = false;
                    //filterUIObject.filterTextInput.text = "";
                    break;                      
                }
            }               
        }
    }
```

Whenever I debug, the code in above event handler always goes into the 'IF' block, never enters the 'ELSE' block (even though the initial value was set to 'FALSE').

Is it because I am storing the control references in an Object? If YES, what can be done to retrieve the correct value?

Comment: do not dispatch a MouseEvent, work with custom event. You are confusing yourself and the Flash Player by using a built in event that is actually dispatched at the same time. No matter what each time you click anywhere a MouseEvent is dispatched so if you dispatch another one on top of it don't be surprise if you run into confusing troubles. Your problem will never be fixed until you stop dispatching MouseEvent.

Comment: Ok, I can try that way. But I have a question- I have tied the Mouse-click event to the specific checkbox, still it will create ambiguity?

Comment: of course that checkbox does dispatch mouseevent internally, if you make it dispatch more mouseevent they will be processed internally as well and create confusion.

Comment: @BotMaster... Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, we are supposed to avoid creating custom events in our project. The architecture discourages this approach. I have further realized that the statement 'filterUIObject.filterCheckBox.selected = false;' maynot be working as expected since the checkbox reference is stored in the object- filterUIObject.  Is there any other workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try spark checkbox instead of mx checkbox, if your component is spark your code will work.
To fix in mx(Halo theme), you can use change event instead of mouse click event try this code

```
filterUIObject.filterCheckBox.selected = false;    
filterUIObject.filterCheckBox.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));  
private function checkBoxClickHandler(event:Event):void
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arulkumar, the "Event.CHANGE" is working perfect. I think my guess was right, the checkbox reference stored in an Object made it difficult to store the "selected" property and hence it was not fetching the correct value. Thanks again! :)